# short-term high humidity due to rain

Tags: humidity

I know that indoor humidity should be <60%. If it is 80% for a week due to a week of rain, is this a problem, if when it stops raining it returns to 50-60%? The house is in PA, where humidity is not always a problem (like FL), but we have had very high levels outside for a week.

Comment: Doors and wooden cabinets could get sticky for a while. The problems usually fix themselves once the humidity goes back down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above 60%, mold spores multiply and people with respiratory issues become uncomfortable. It should go back down soon with no major issues other than a slight permanent increase in the amount of musty smells in the house when all the windows are closed due to the new mold spores. Don't let it stay above 80% for extended periods of time, though. If you're bothered, run your AC or use a dehumidifier.